# Odd Even number in a single Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want The List Of `Odd` And `Even` Number in a single Query, I just find out Just one of the odd or even, Below is my code

```
SELECT * FROM 
 ( SELECT T.C_DATE,T.C_NAME,T.C_TIME,L_UID, ROWNUM RANK 
     FROM TENTER T)
    WHERE MOD(RANK,2)=1
      AND C_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
    ORDER BY L_UID, C_TIME ASC;
```

Comment: Remove `MOD(RANK,2)=1` from your query and you get odd and even numbers. Why do you even have this criteria in your `WHERE` clause when you don't want this restriction? Apart from that: Are you aware that `ROWNUM` is completely arbitrary and can be different the next time you run the query? In short: What is it you actually want to achieve? Please show sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: sample input and output data please??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this without a subquery.  Assuming you just want a label on each row:

```
SELECT T.C_DATE, T.C_NAME, T.C_TIME, L_UID, ROWNUM as RANK,
       (CASE WHEN MOD(ROWNUM, 2) = 0 THEN 'EVEN' ELSE 'ODD' END) as even_odd_label 
FROM TENTER T
WHERE C_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE 
ORDER BY L_UID, C_TIME ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

you might use :

```
SELECT decode(mod(TT.RANK,2),0,'Even','Odd') as rank,
       TT.*
  FROM 
 ( SELECT T.C_DATE,T.C_NAME,T.C_TIME,L_UID, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY L_UID, C_TIME ASC) as RANK 
     FROM TENTER T) TT
    WHERE C_DATE BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE
    ORDER BY L_UID, C_TIME ASC;
```

P.S. By the way I suggest you using `ROW_NUMBER` function with certain order numbers instead of system-generated `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Barbaros Ozhan   But i want that List, Don't wanna count.

Comment: @LitonBiswas welcome, ok, but how do you want to count..? With respect to which column..?

Comment: Thanks I want to List Of ODD ROWNUM AND EVEN ROWNUM  By date.

Comment: ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block